# Connect to MySQL - how to tell

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can I connect a PHP to mysql using this code? I don't know how to check that code, is it connected or not. Now its successfully connected, but when I opened that PHP I got error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pencatatan\koneksi.php on line 6

```
 <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'pencatatan';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

Comment: It seems to me that you would need some kind of object for conn that expects your db['default'] associative array as a configuration parameter. So no. There is nothing in your code that is actually attempting to make the connection.

Comment: Literally all you're doing in this code is create an array and then use an undefined variable (named `$conn`). What would you expect would happen? Just because you create an array doesn't mean it automatically knows that you're trying to connect to a database. You need to use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: You are not opening a connection. $conn is not created

Comment: See this manual page, shreds some light on the subject: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: i'll try it guys, thanks for the help :D

Comment: If you're using PHP 7.0, the outdated mysql_* API calls have finally been removed. You'll need to use mysqli, PDO, or a framework to handle communication with the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a connection. You set a variable with all connection strings but you are not initiating the connection in $conn.

See the example below. You don't have the row below // Create connection

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$server_name = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="pencatatan";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if($conn->connect_error) {
die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is you are trying to connect db... but in your code you defined only $conn without initiate the property of that..

so please put above $conn->connect_error,

put this... $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

Comment: Adding this peace of code will not work with the example above. The variables are not matching